# Not able to open websites home page using jMeter, getting an error

Tags: jmeter

Not able to open websites home page using jMeter, getting an error

Using following configuration

jmeter version: 2.13
and I just trying to open google page and same error getting while opening my website's page.

Please refer screenshots for settings and results.

[image: Setting of my request]

[image: Sampler result]

[image: Request]

[image: Response data]

Comment: Do you use some kind of proxy or port forwarding? If you use proxy - do you configure JMeter accordingly? If you use port forwarding - are ports configured properly and forwarded at the time when you attempt to run the test?

Answer (score 0):

Test scenario itself is correct. Seems like something is wrong with JVM. Any info messages in console after start? 
Try with google IP instead of hostname to make sure that it's not a DNS issue.
Did you run it with any specific flags like -H or -P? Do you use proxy?